# How to update from subquery with query builder?

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine

I'm using Symfony 5, Doctrine, and PostgreSQL.

In some Transaction Repository I'm trying to run the code below:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->em->createQueryBuilder('tr');
$queryBuilder2 = $this->em->createQueryBuilder('t');

$queryBuilder2->select('t.id', 't.status')
    ->where(
        $queryBuilder->expr()->isNotNull('t.timeoutAt'),
        $queryBuilder->expr()->lt('t.timeoutAt', ':timeoutAt'),
        $queryBuilder->expr()->in('t.status', ':status')
    )->setParameters([
        'timeoutAt' => Carbon::now(TimezoneEnum::UTC),
        'status' => ['pending', 'done'],
    ])->getDQL();


$queryBuilder->update()
    ->set(
        't.status',
        'CASE WHEN t.status = :statusPending THEN :statusDone ELSE :statusInProgress END'
    )
    ->set('tr.updatedAt', ':updatedAt')
    ->from($queryBuilder2->getDQL(), 't')
    ->where('t.id = tr.id')
    ->setParameters([
        'updatedAt' => Carbon::now(TimezoneEnum::UTC),
        'statusPending' => 'pending',
        'statusDone' => 'done',
        'statusInProgress' => 'progress',
    ]);
```

After calling `$queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();` I got an error:

> Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException : [Syntax Error] line 0, col 37: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_SET, got ','

If to remove `->from($queryBuilder2->getDQL(), 't')` error will be fixed, but I need this FROM.

Also `$queryBuilder2->getQuery()->getResult()` working perfect;

**How to correctly put sql of $querybuilder2 to FROM part?**

Comment: just a verification: you are selecting 'peding' and 'done' transactions to update them
you have this `CASE WHEN t.status = :statusPending THEN :statusDone ELSE :statusInProgress END`, which will make 'done' transitions to be 'progress', is what you want also ?

Comment: @yassinefikri thank you, it's just fake values, that properly works, just for example:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should be what you want

it will update the status and the updatedAt, for only 'pending' and 'done' transations

the getSingleScalarResult() will let you know how much transactions got updated,

change it as you need

```
return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->update(Transaction::class, 't')
            ->set('t.status', 'CASE WHEN t.status = :statusPending THEN :statusDone ELSE :statusInProgress END')
            ->set('t.updatedAt', ':updatedAt')
            ->where('t.status IN (:statuses)')
            ->andWhere('t.timeoutAt is NOT NULL')
            ->andWhere('t.timeoutAt < :timeoutAt')
            ->setParameter('statuses', ['pending', 'done'])
            ->setParameter('updatedAt', Carbon::now(TimezoneEnum::UTC))
            ->setParameter('statusPending','pending')
            ->setParameter('statusDone', 'done')
            ->setParameter('statusInProgress', 'progress')
            ->setParameter('timeoutAt', Carbon::now(TimezoneEnum::UTC))
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Comment: what is the value of :timeoutAt ?

Comment: Carbon::now(TimezoneEnum::UTC)